# Javascript - Detect open window. My code does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not very good at javascript but my code does not work as I hope.

I try to make myself understood.
On the home page I have the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function popitup(url) {
           newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=650,width=312');
           if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
           return false;
        }
        // -->
    </script>
```

This code, as you know, puts me a popup of 312x650.
Then I put the following in the link that will open:

```
<a href="" onClick="return popitup('escuchar.php?id=<?=$v['link']?>')"><?=$v['titulo']?></a>
```

Ok, the code works perfect but within this "popup" I put another link which returns me to the main page.
The problem was that I opened a new window, then basing on the above code, put it in the html popup javascript code as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function popitup() {
           url = "index.php"
           newwindow=window.open(url,'Amixer Music');
           if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        }
        // -->
    </script>
```

This code does not work 100%.
I pretended that I had detected me open a page called "amixer Music" and if it was not, to open this.

Then when I click the link that is in the popup and I would have to return to the main page:

```
<a href="javascript:popitup();" id="volver" title="Ve a la página principal y busca tu música!">Busca tus canciones!</a>
```

This opens a new window and ignores that I already have it open.
And if I give back to click the link, it seems the code works because I do not open another window but I reload the window that opened at the beginning.

Example of my error:
http://traductoramixer.x10.bz/javascript/

Comment: Don't use space in the [window's name argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open), i.e. use for example `Amixer_Music`.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, jsFiddle gives me an error about "POST". Anyway I've uploaded to a server for you to see. http://traductoramixer.x10.bz/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

In your popup, do this:

```
function popitup() {
    if(window.opener !== null && window.opener.length && 
        /^http\:\/\/traductoramixer\.x10\.bz\/javascript\/(index.html)?$/i.test(window.opener.location.href)){
        //If the main page is present,
        window.opener.focus();
        window.close();  //optional
    }else{
        //If not,
        var url = "index.php",
            newwindow = window.open(url, 'Amixer Music');
        if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus(); }
    }
}
```

I believe this will work.